# Is there a limit on consumers and consumer groups?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any limit on the number of consumers or consumer groups in Kafka?

I am planning to push 200 MB of data every 10 mins to a topic and have 200+ distinct consumers listen and consume from this topic. Is there any other recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kafka, there is no limit on the number of Consumer groups for a particular topic. However, the increase in consumer groups increases network utilization.

Worth nothing that newer versions of Kafka, store offsets in the internal Kafka topic called `__consumer_offsets`.

Answer (score 9):

As Rohit answer states, there' no such limit.

Regarding your issue, it seems like you want to achieve some kind of paralellization of consumption. If you send 200 consumers with 200 different consumer groups, each consumer will read all the data independently, so you'll have **200 threads reading the same 200MB every 10 minutes** *(200x200 MB = 40GB received every 10 minutes).* I guess you wanted every consumer to read 1MB every 10 mins with your approach, but that's not how it works.

If the logic implemented by each consumer is the same, you shouldn't declare more than a consumer group. If you declare two consumer groups, each one will read the same data, and you'll just repeat the job done, duplicating the output. Set different consumer groups if the job to be done on the topic's records is different: for example, one consumer group must store the records into a DDBB. The other consumer group must visualize the data into Grafana. Those are two different processing mechanisms, so each one must read all the data at its own. This is not the only reason to declare different consumer groups, but one example of them. There are multiple justifications for declaring more than a consumer group for a topic.

Imagine an scenario **where the only job to be done is storing the messages into a DDBB. If you declare two consumer groups and launch your consumers, what you'll get is duplicate values stored in your database**, as the first consumer group is just doing the same work than the second. Not only you are re-reading from kafka, you are re-storing the same messages into the ddbb.

In order to achieve launching multiple consumers that efficiently share the work (so for example, launching 4 consumers each one reads 50MB), you must **partition your topic**.

Only one consumer thread from the same consumer group can read from an specific partition. If you have 4 partitions in that topic, and 4 consumer threads that share the same consumer group, launching them will lead to each thread reading from one partition. If you launch two consumers, both will be assigned 2 partitions. Works like this:

[image]

And in this scenario, **you do have a limit in the number of consumers concurrently reading if they share the same consumer group, which is, the number of partitions of that topic**. If you launch a 5th consumer thread, one of them will block/wait, because it wasn't assigned any partition. In the example, consumer 5 waits until a partition is avaliable for him (*so maybe waits forever*).

[image]

---

What I suggest is: **decide how many consumer threads you'll need to consume the data and partition the topic in base of that**. If you, for example, partition the topic to 8 different partitions, you'll be able to launch 8 consumers from the same consumer group. Each one will then read, more or less, (*depending on the producer partitioner*) **25MB *(200/8)*** of the incoming data, efficiently sharing the work load: Each consumer will read from its own partition.

- If you launch 200 consumers with 200 different consumer groups,
  **you'll just multiply the work to be done `x200`**, as every single consumer will read the data from start to end.
- If you launch 200 consumers with the same consumer group and the topic has a single partition,
  **you'll have one thread doing all the job and 199 stale consumers**.

Comment: That's a great explanation. Crystal clear. Thanks a lot for this Aran. In my case, all 200+ distinct remote servers (or you can say partners) are supposed to consume the same data, because they are independent of each other. 

So I take it as "No limit, keeping an eye on the network utilisation".

Comment: Glad to help @ArunKolhapur! I assumed everything but your specific context xD. Hope at least the answer was somehow useful for future cases. Sincerely thanks for your words, have a nice day mate!